# Why is the sample code from Yahoo Social SDK for PHP always returns NULL for the session variable?

Tags: php, sdk, yahoo-api

[I am trying to get the sample code from the Yahoo Social SDK for PHP page to work, With no luck.](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/php/)

This is the code snippet from the site:

```
<?php  
  require("Yahoo.inc");  

  // Your Consumer Key (API Key) goes here.  
  define('CONSUMER_KEY', "");  

  // Your Consumer Secret goes here.  
  define('CONSUMER_SECRET', "");  

  // Your application ID goes here.  
  define('APPID', "");  

  $session = YahooSession::requireSession(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,APPID);  
?>
```

I set the `CONSUMER_KEY`, `CONSUMER_SECRET` and `APPID`. **But the `$session variable` is always NULL.**

After digging around the yahoo.inc source code i traced the problem to this function:

```
function getRequestToken($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $callback);
```

specifically this call in the function:

```
$response = $client->post($request_url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $parameters);
$request_url: https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token
$parameters: has my callback url
```

And the `$response` variable is `null` !! which i think is the source of the problem.
I am using the sample codes as it is. So, I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any ideas ?? What I am missing ?

Comment: can you check error_log file ? or enable error_reporting error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: do session_start() at start of your php file or use this https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php/blob/master/sample/sampleapp.php

Comment: I checked the error logs, and there a mention of curl having a SSL problem. so I added this line to Yahoo.inc:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

now it's working...thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$yahooUserData = YahooSession::requireSession($yahooConsumerKey, $yahooConsumerSecret, $yahooAppId, $returnUrl);

if (!empty($yahooUserData)) {
  $yahooUserId = $yahooUserData->guid;
  $accessToken = $yahooUserData->accessToken->key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify return url and Try this ...

```
$yahooUserData = YahooSession::requireSession($yahooConsumerKey, $yahooConsumerSecret, $yahooAppId, $returnUrl);

if (!empty($yahooUserData)) {
  $yahooUserId = $yahooUserData->guid;
  $accessToken = $yahooUserData->accessToken->key;
}
```